# ios singleton faults core data objects

Tags: ios, core-data, singleton, magicalrecord

I have singleton with init block

```
@implementation WSession

static WSession *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];    
    return self;
}
```

It has a property of CoreData object

```
@property (nonatomic) WPlaces *authorizedPlace;
```

I go between screens i use this property, and save other CoreData object with MagicalRecord MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait

But some times singleton fails link to this property and it change to nil.

Why?

in xCode debug

```
<WPlaces: 0xa8546e0> (entity: WPlaces; id: 0xa858430 <x-coredata://38FEE7D9-CD17-48B9-891C-D9E0A0142478/WPlaces/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

On authorization screen

```
po [WSession sharedInstance].authorizedPlace
<WPlaces: 0xa8546e0> (entity: WPlaces; id: 0xa858430 <x-coredata://38FEE7D9-CD17-48B9-891C-D9E0A0142478/WPlaces/p1> ; data: {
    desc = "\U041f\U043e\U0433\U043e\U0440\U0435\U043b\U043e\U0432\U0430 \U0418\U041f";
    key = "0dbea37a-4a16-4c30-821c-3819a2741f60";
    name = "\U041c\U0430\U0440\U0448\U0430\U043b\U0430 \U0416\U0443\U043a\U043e\U0432\U0430 \U0443\U043b\U0438\U0446\U0430 18";
    tag = "\U041c\U043e\U0441\U043a\U0432\U0430";
})
```

But on next screen already

```
po [WSession sharedInstance].authorizedPlace
<WPlaces: 0xa8546e0> (entity: WPlaces; id: 0xa858430 <x-coredata://38FEE7D9-CD17-48B9-891C-D9E0A0142478/WPlaces/p1> ; data: <fault>)

(lldb) po [[WSession sharedInstance].authorizedPlace valueForKeyPath:@"key"]
 nil
(lldb) po [[WSession sharedInstance].authorizedPlace valueForKeyPath:@"name"]
 nil
(lldb)
```

Comment: What happens if you use valueForKey: or objectForKey: (not keyPath)?

Comment: How is the NSManagedObjectContext that owns this object created? Where is the context retained?

Comment: Where is your context at? Is it alive through the life of your singleton?